# How to fix MongoTemplate --> MappingMongoConverter --> BeforeConvertCallback --> MongoTemplate circular dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create a custom Auditing callback in order to set the corresponding fields of my MongoDB documents.

This is my callback:

```
@Order(101)
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditingCallback implements BeforeConvertCallback<AuditingDocument<String>> {
    private final AuditingConfiguration auditingConfiguration;

    @Setter
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    /**
     * Entity callback method invoked before a domain object is converted to be persisted. Can return either the same or a
     * modified instance of the domain object.
     *
     * @param entity     the domain object to save.
     * @param collection name of the collection.
     * @return the domain object to be persisted.
     */
    @Override
    public AuditingDocument<String> onBeforeConvert(AuditingDocument<String> entity, String collection) {
        System.out.println("Auditing Callback");
        System.out.println(entity);

        if(this.isNew(entity)){
            System.out.println("Is new");
                entity.setCreator(this.auditingConfiguration.getCurrentAuditor().orElse(null));
            entity.setCreated(Instant.now());
        }else{
            System.out.println("Is not new");

            // TODO
            // Retrieve existing creator, created
            Class<AuditingDocument<String>> clazz = (Class<AuditingDocument<String>>) entity.getClass();
            AuditingDocument<String> existingEntity = this.mongoTemplate.<AuditingDocument<String>>findById(entity.getId(), clazz);

            System.out.println("Existing Entity:");
            System.out.println(existingEntity);

            entity.setModifier(this.auditingConfiguration.getCurrentAuditor().orElse(null));
            entity.setModified(Instant.now());
        }

        return entity;
    }

    private boolean isNew(AuditingDocument<String> entity){
        return StringUtils.isBlank(entity.getId());
    }
}
```

Now I need to find the existing entity from the DB, to keep the existing creator and created fields, hence the MongoTemplate field.

This results in a circular dependency:

```
┌─────┐
|  mongoTemplate defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  mappingMongoConverter defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  auditingCallback (field private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations org.myproject.configuration.database.auditing.callbacks.AuditingCallback.mongoOperations)
└─────┘
```

How can I break this circular dependency?
I also tried with MongoOperations but it is the same.

Note that I am already using the

```
allow-circular-references: true
```

property.

Is it not possible to load existing entities during MongoDB events callbacks?

**Log 2**

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditingCallback': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditingCallback': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditingCallback': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditingCallback': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Comment: Add @Lazy annotation for mongoTemplate may solve your problem.

Comment: No way. Tried both @Lazy and setter method.

Comment: facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue, though adding @Lazy solved it for me